# Nested IF in Excel Formula with changing IMAGE value

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, nested-if

so I have an Excel workbook wherein a table if you enter a value

0 = you'll get a **Red** colour image

1 = you'll get a **yellow** colour image

2 = you'll get a **Green** colour image

I'm trying to meet a condition where

1. If Risk Score is more than Control Score by 2 should be RED (0)
2. If Risk Score  is more than Control Score by 1 should be YELLOW (1)
3. If Risk Score is less than or equal to  Control Score should be GREEN (2)

This is my formula

```
=IF(AND(C13<=K3, C13=K3), 2,IF(AND(C13=K3, C13>=K3), 1, ))
```

[image]

But I'm not able to meet the conditions above.

This is the excel file.
https://ufile.io/3udr8wgr

---

Comment: The two elements in your and function are causing the formulas to zero out, if you just do =IF(AND(C13<=K3),2,IF(AND(C13>=K3), 1 )) the above data will then return 2

Comment: If I add your formula it doesn't return 0 (RED), for example, if the Risk Score is higher than Control it should return 0 (RED), in this case, there is no RED.